# check facebook login with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I created this facebook api script:

```
FB.api('/me/likes/112234512170409',function(response) {
    if( response.data ) {
        if( !isEmpty(response.data) )
            alert('You are a fan!');
        else
            alert('Not a fan!');
    } else {
        alert('ERROR!');
                 alert("Error: " + response.error.message);

    }
});
```

But I always get error messages: Error: an active acces token must be used to...
Here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/zfS6rgpj
What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since your script is in the body and not the head, and you simply execute the code you want instead of defining it within a function to call later on, you are running the API request (Line #37 of your code) immediately on document load, which is before you are logged in (hence, no valid token). I would wrap your API call with a function so you can call it later, e.g.

```
var callMeLater = function {
   FB.api('/me/likes/112234512170409',function(response) {
   ...
};
```

And call `callMeLater();` after you've logged in.

If you haven't already checked it out, perhaps steps 4 and 5 may be helpful to you in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Let me know if your problem works out or if you need me to clarify anything :)